# cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called after table reload in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I am facing a very strange issue. I am doing the following

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   [invoiceTable reloadData]; // my table    
}
```

After doing this my control will be transfered to

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  if(tableview == invoiceTable) {

     return 5;
  }
  else {

     return 6;    
  }
}
```

But `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for `invoiceTable` is not being called. I have connected datasource and delegate properly.

Comment: How did you connect them?

Comment: Using IBOutlet. i.e dragging from the view to class

Comment: Could you put a *NSLog* and see what happens?

Comment: I have checked it . cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called after the tableview is reloaded

Comment: Try to print the invoiceTable object on viewWillAppear after reloading  tableview.

Comment: Do you have a valid outlet connection for your table?

Comment: Yes.. I think the actual problem is my tableview is above the image view since I want background image for the tableview. This image view i have not declared any where

Comment: It is creating the problem because I have 3 table view . One under main View and other two upon the ImageView which is inside the main view

Comment: Does your table load the data for the first time?

Answer (score -1):

Create one function and reload the table and call that function in didselect.

```
-(void)function
{ 
[tableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help at all. What on earth is that supposed to accomplish?